«du français» vs. «de français» in the name of the French language knowledge assessment test (TCF, TEF)
Recently, I've seen two tests for the French language knowledge assessment:

Test de connaissance du français (TCF)
Test d'évaluation de français (TEF)

Why in the case of TCF, is it written as «du français», while for TEF a form of «de français» is used instead?

It's the same difference as "my knowledge of Japanese is limited" vs "my Japanese test was hard". You don't say "my test of Japanese".
In French we don't say "mon test du japonais", it would mean that you're testing out Japanese as a language. We use "test de japonais" instead.
But we do say "ma connaissance [de le =]du japonais" because you can know Japanese as a language.
"Test d'évaluation de français" is a slightly more complex expression since "test" and "évaluation" are kind of synonyms and you could debate for hours which of the two "de français" complements, but you get the idea. It's "de" because it's a French test and not you testing French.

Thx! From your explanation I got that it should be test de français and not test du français. So, why is it used connaissance du français and not connaissance de français in case of TCF?

@Mike I edited my answer. Hope it clarifies things. Of course you need to know basic grammar rules such as "de + le = du", etc.

In the first NP, the word "français"  is found in a relation of object of the word "connaissance": "connaitre quoi ? connaitre le français". The usual preposition for that relation is "de", and the definite article is retained if there is one (there is one in the case of nouns).

connaissance du (de le) voisinage, connaissance des (de les) choses de l'autre monde, connaissance de la vie, …
connaissance de soi même, connaissance d'autres personnes, connaissance de tout et de rien, connaissance de nombreuses choses, … (These NP and pronouns have no usual article, so  "de" appears in full.)

In the second  NP, the word "français" is not found in a relation of object of the word "test": what is being appraised is not the French language. Here the relation is one that expresses the sort of something. It is also rendered by means of the preposition "de", but, great difference the usual article is not retained.

test de compréhension, test de notions élémentaires, test de fin d'étude, test de vérification, etc.

"Français" as could be deduced from the explanation above is not analyzed as "complément du nom « évaluation », but a "complément du nom « test ».
There may be some overlapping at times in the usage that is made of those forms; for instance "test de fin de trimestre" et "test de la fin du trimestre" may both be used to name a sort of test; however "test de la fin du trimestre"  denotes properly a relation of time between "test" and "fin de trimestre".

Et test de fin du trimestre aussi, pas de problème, tout comme test d'évaluation du français, et test de connaissance de français.

Connaissance de voisinage est également possible, quoique le sens change.

"[...]the word "français" is not found in a relation of object of the word "test": what is being appraised is not the French language." Shiver my timbers.

@Lambie Shivers me timbers.

@Frank My language, my style. And in fact, it's: "shiver me timbers". It's vocative.

Sure - good news is, don't meet too many pirates these days.
